# Abbout Memcache logic

Tags: caching, memcached

Does the data stored in cache/memory by memcache differ for every user or result would be same for all?

Does it store data in servers cache or user's memory?

e.g.

```
$dynamic_data_from_sql = "Whatever";
$memcache->set('key', $dynamic_data_from_sql, false, 60);   //Store for 1 minute
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The contents of a memcache server are the same for all connections from any user.
2. the data is stored in the memcache server's memory, not the client's memory.

Answer (score 0):

PREAMBLE:
1 - every `object` in memcached is a couple . where `value` is the object requested by the user (i.e. the result of a query in a db) and cached by server. while the `key` is the key associated to the `value` that should be unique and is used to retrieve the  `value`.

2 - memcache is a distribuited cache: it means that there is a server (ore more than one) that collects objects requested by clients , and there are clients potentially far(not too much) from server.. so data collected by a server is memory of the server itself. in particular when you start the server you have to specify an amount of memory to assign to him.

said that: if two users request the very same object, the result will be the same for each user.

hope you understand my english (=